# How to detect whether the option citecounter was enabled on biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, optional-arguments, package-options, class-options, options

I think this is the definition of the `citecounter` option on the `biblatex` package:

```latex
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{citecounter}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@opt@citecounter@#1}
    {\csuse{blx@opt@citecounter@#1}}
    {\blx@err@invopt{citecounter=#1}{}}}
\def\blx@opt@citecounter@true{%
  \let\blx@setcitecounter\blx@setcitecounter@global
  \let\blx@citecounter\blx@citecounter@global
  \let\abx@aux@count\blx@aux@count
  \let\abx@aux@fncount\blx@aux@fncount
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@opt@citecounter@context{%
  \let\blx@setcitecounter\blx@setcitecounter@context
  \let\blx@citecounter\blx@citecounter@context
  \let\abx@aux@count\blx@aux@count
  \let\abx@aux@fncount\blx@aux@fncount
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@opt@citecounter@false{%
  \let\blx@setcitecounter\relax
  \let\blx@citecounter\relax
  \let\abx@aux@count\@gobbletwo
  \let\abx@aux@fncount\@gobbletwo}
```

Then, what can I use to know whether the option was enabled?

For example:

```
\usepackage[style=abnt,language=english,citecounter=false]{biblatex}

\if citecounter=false
    \message{Citecounter is false^^J}

\else
    \message{Citecounter is enabled^^J}
\fi
```

Related:

1. [Can I count the number of times each reference is cited?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/can-i-count-the-number-of-times-each-reference-is-cited)
2. [How to detect whether \PassOptionsToPackage was already called?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483570/how-to-detect-whether-passoptionstopackage-was-already-called)
3. [Nested \ifdefined statements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207893/nested-ifdefined-statements)
4. [Checking if certain package option is declared inside .sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423024/checking-if-certain-package-option-is-declared-inside-sty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted definition shows that `\blx@citecounter` is equal to `\relax` if and only if the `citecounter` feature is deactivated. So you can check for that.

One way would be

```
\ifcsvoid{blx@citecounter}
  {NO CITECOUNTER}
  {CITECOUNTER}
```

(Technically, `\ifcsvoid{blx@citecounter}` tests if `\blx@citecounter` is `\relax` or a parameterless macro with empty replacement, but that should be good enough here.)

If you want to stick to TeX conditionals

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\blx@citecounter\relax
  NO CITECOUNTER%
\else
  CITECOUNTER%
\fi
\makeatother
```

would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `citecounter`, I can also check whether `backref` was set too. Given the source for the `backref` option on `biblatex` package:

```latex
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{backref}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\let\blx@backref\blx@addbackref
     \let\abx@aux@backref\blx@aux@backref
     \booltrue{backtracker}}
    {\let\blx@backref\@gobble
     \let\abx@aux@backref\@gobblefive
     \boolfalse{backtracker}}}
```

I can check whether both `citetracker` and `backref` were set with:

```
\usepackage[style=abnt,language=english,backend=biber,citecounter=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\ifx\blx@citecounter\relax
  \message{citecounter defined!^^J}
\else
  \message{citecounter not defined!^^J}
\fi
\makeatother

\ifcitetracker
  \message{citetracker defined!^^J}
\else
  \message{citetracker not defined!^^J}
\fi

\ifbacktracker
  \message{backref defined!^^J}
\else
  \message{backref not defined!^^J}
\fi
```

Comment: Note that the `citetracker` bool as tested with `\ifcitetracker` is activated by several options (`citecounter` being one of them) and need not mean that the tracking *option* `citetracker` has been enabled.